# Add a block to knockout template but not using checkout config provider

Tags: magento2

I have a knockout html in my theme `app\design\frontend\Vendor\themeName\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart` content.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block-title">
    <button type="button"
            id="btn-minicart-close"
            class="action close"
            data-action="close"
            data-bind="
                attr: {
                    title: $t('Close')
                },
                click: closeMinicart()
            ">
        <span translate="'Close'"/>
    </button>
    <strong>
        <span class="text" translate="'My Cart'"/>
        <span
            class="qty empty"
            text="getCartParam('summary_count')"
            data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false },
                       attr: { title: $t('Items in Cart') }">
        </span>
    </strong>
</div>

<div class="block-content">
    <if args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <div class="items-total">
            <span class="count" if="maxItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()" text="maxItemsToDisplay"/>
            <translate args="'of'" if="maxItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
            <span class="count" text="getCartParam('summary_count')"/>
                <!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() === 1) -->
                    <span translate="'Item in Cart'"/>
                <!--/ko-->
                <!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() > 1) -->
                    <span translate="'Items in Cart'"/>
                <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        
        <div class="actions top">
            <each args="getRegion('subtotalContainer')" render=""/>
            <each args="getRegion('extraInfo')" render=""/>
            <div class="primary"  if="getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout')">
                <button
                        id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                        type="button"
                        class="action primary checkout"
                        data-action="close"
                        data-bind="
                            attr: {
                                title: $t('Proceed to Checkout')
                            },
                            click: closeMinicart()
                        "
                        translate="'Proceed to Checkout'"
                />
                <div data-bind="html: getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml('extra_actions')"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </if>

    <if args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <strong class="subtitle" translate="'Recently added item(s)'"/>
        <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
            <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartItems(), as: 'item' }">
                <each args="$parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type))"
                      render="{name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}}"
                />
            </ol>
        </div>
    </if>

    <ifnot args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <strong class="subtitle empty"
                translate="'You have no items in your shopping cart.'"
        />
        <if args="getCartParam('cart_empty_message')">
            <p class="minicart empty text" text="getCartParam('cart_empty_message')"/>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                        <span translate="'View and Edit Cart'"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </if>
    </ifnot>

    
    <div class="actions bottom" if="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <span translate="'View and Edit Cart'"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets" if="regionHasElements('promotion')">
        <each args="getRegion('promotion')" render=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<each args="getRegion('sign-in-popup')" render=""/>
```

This part of code is not in checkout step but there is in product details page, so i've tried to use checkout config provider but it only run in checkout step so it didn't work for my case.

Do anyone know how to add a block in knockout html other than using check config provider?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I spent a lot of hours looking at how templates and other stuff are related with knockout.js, I will try to explain how to subtotal price format is displayed to order summary at checkout module but is the same to other things too. My current version is Magento ver. 2.0.4.

First, if you navigate to the corresponding layout file for checkout at

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Detailed answer at: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135098/101754

Comment: those answer is still using checkout config provider. my question is "not using checkout config provider"